# Determining first occurrence in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm very new to Python but I've looked around and haven't seen anything that would match what I'm trying to do.

I'm using PyGame for collision detection between three objects (a ball, square A, square B). What I want to do is have X occur if the ball hits square B, but only if it has hit square A before. Because this is inside a continuously occurring loop, I cannot simply set ballAcollide as true when it occurs because it will be reset immediately.

I currently have something that works, but I'm sure it's an ugly workaround and there's a better way to do it. Here is the code snippet in question:

```
def fastball(ball, squareA, squareB):
    # This needs to be improved
    if ball.rect.colliderect(squareA.rect):
        # do unrelated
        global firsthit
        firsthit = False
    elif ball.rect.colliderect(squareB.rect):
        try:
            if not firsthit:
                # do X
        except NameError:
            # do nothing
```

Comment: why doesn't `ball` have a flag saying `hitAfirst`? Also, your code looks like X is performed if the ball hits B and A hasn't been hit instead of only if A has been hit first

Comment: why hasnt `ball` a deque of size(2) that gets the hits appended and you check front/back for a/b to see if it hit em in the right order?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I edited my question to include what I wrote based on your suggestion (or at least what I thought you were suggesting!)

Comment: add it as self answer, you neeed to wait 48 hours and can accept it after that time. nice it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer based on PatrickArtner's suggestion:

```
def fastball2(ball, squareA, squareB, list):
    if ball.rect.colliderect(squareA.rect):
        if len(list) == 0:
            list.append('A')
        # do unrelated
    elif ball.rect.colliderect(squareB.rect) and len(list) > 0:
        # do x
```

list is then flushed at a different point in the loop if certain conditions are met. Appreciate the help!